DAX Measure to Check if Any Rows Fall Within a Specified Range
I'm working on a Power BI project and I need to create a DAX measure to check if any rows in a table fall within a specified range based on a dynamic value.
Specifically, I have a table CountryDeliveryTable with a column CountryDeliveryRank representing the ranking of countries based on delivery. I also have a measure [SelectedCountryRank_2] that dynamically calculates the rank of the selected country. Now, I want to create a DAX measure checkinRange2 that returns 1 if there are any rows in CountryDeliveryTable with a CountryDeliveryRank falling within +/- 2 ranks of the selected country's rank, and 0 otherwise.
Here's the DAX expression I've tried so far:
checkinRange2 = 
VAR LowerBound = [SelectedCountryRank_2] - 2
VAR UpperBound = [SelectedCountryRank_2] + 2

RETURN
    IF(
        COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                ALL(CountryDeliveryTable),
                CountryDeliveryTable[CountryDeliveryRank] >= LowerBound && CountryDeliveryTable[CountryDeliveryRank] <= UpperBound
            )
        ) > 0,
        1,
        0
    )

However, this expression is returning 1 for all rows, regardless of whether they fall within the specified range or not.
Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue and provide a correct DAX expression to achieve my desired outcome?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

It's difficult to say without viewing the data model, but if you remove all the filters from CountryDeliveryTable, it's possible that at least one country is in that range.
